# Running a command line on a remote server

Tags: java, servlets

I have a command (actually it is a Hadoop job command like) "hadoop jar " that 
needs to be run on a server whose ip address I know.

How can I invoke the command from inside my java code?

Thanks
Abhishek S

Comment: You can use "RMI" or "WebService"

Answer (score 0):

Implement additional two applications, the first runs on the server and launches your command, the second runs on the client side and sends commands to the server via network socket connection. Server app receives client request and runs required command line on the server host.

To execute a command on the local host (for server-side application), use [Runtime class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html) and its `exec()` method.